# Add activity to Manifest without extends Activity

Tags: android, class, android-manifest

I have class and I need add these class to Manifest as activity, but these class is:  public class SFMusic extends Service {...}. In android Manifest: 
`<activity android:name="SFMusic" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>`

How do I add the class to Android Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation for `Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> Each service class must have a corresponding `<service>` declaration in its package's `AndroidManifest.xml`.

See also [the overview of services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Declaring), plus the material on services in any decent Android app development book or course.